# CSS working different on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css

I've got a table with some divs inside its cells. This divs should expand to the 100% height of the cell, and they do in Chrome, but not in Firefox. I attach a picture of the difference:

[image]

The CSS for the table cells is:

```
td {
  height: 100% !important;
  vertical-align: top !important;
}
```

And for the divs inside them:

```
.div-box {
  height: 100% !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Shouldn't this code work the same on different browsers?

Thanks.

Comment: add a working fiddle

Comment: *"Shouldn't this code work the same on different browsers?"* - Not if the browsers don't want it too.

Comment: There are a lot of reasons why this would be the case, one of them begin browser default CSS. Without a working example, we'll never be able to find out..

Comment: Chrome is sometimes more forgiving than Firefox - But we can't see it without an example

Comment: Chrome and firefox don't agree on many things - look at this for example : https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/Kiwaz open in both browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Just for trying, I added the 'height' property to the 'tr' tag and it works fine both in Chrome and Firefox, the divs take up the 100% height of the cells where they are. So, I added this to the CSS:

```
tr {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Perhaps Firefox is more strict with this than Chrome...